# Blender Python Package Cannot be Resolved in VSCode

Tags: python, python-import

I'm trying to get Blender's python library (bpy) working with VSCode but for some reason despite having the correct interpreter selected, VSCode cannot resolve the package. What's strange is that Jupyter autocomplete has no issues.

Other libraries, such as numpy, import without any issues.

Note that bpy also imports several other modules such as bmesh, bpy_types, and mathutils. None of those resolve either. The integrated terminal has no issues importing any of these packages.

Does anyone have any recommendations for how to force VSCode to recognize bpy?

[image: broken imports]